# VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch when calling Function

Tags: vbscript

I copied a function that strips html and added some extra replaces into the code, but when I call this function in anywhere I get error with this code

`stripHTML(objRS("Name"))` input are strings, how do I switch or declear the type?

**Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch: 'stripHTML'**

--function.asp

```
function stripHTML(strHTML)
  Dim objRegExp, strOutput, tempStr
  Set objRegExp = New Regexp
  objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
  objRegExp.Global = True
  objRegExp.Pattern = "<(.|n)+?>"
  'Replace all HTML tag matches with the empty string
  strOutput = objRegExp.Replace(strHTML, "")
  'Replace all < and > with &lt; and &gt;
  strOutput = Replace(strOutput, "<", "&lt;")
  strOutput = Replace(strOutput, ">", "&gt;")
  strOutput = Lcase(replace(replace(trim(strOutput),"/","-")," ","-"))
  strOutput = replace(replace(replace(strOutput,".","-"),"&","-"),",","")
  strOutput = replace(replace(strOutput,"--","-"),"---","-")
  stripHTML = strOutput    'Return the value of strOutput
  Set objRegExp = Nothing
end Function
```

**UPDATE**

The place I am calling this function is another file that has this page included at top

sometimes this function will be called by another file THIS page is pulling (example : footer template)

How do I make this function Globally accessible?

Comment: `objRS("Name")` may be NULL. You could guard against this in your SQL query: `select isnull(Name, '') ...`

Comment: They have values this is inside `do while not objRS.EOF` and convert code from something already working. @Bond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out you will still need to deal with NULL(s) but otherwise try:

```
stripHTML(CStr(objRS("Name")))
```